# CSS navigation bar sliding line below text

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

Is it possible to make a line move between links when the mouse is hovered over. With a smooth animation.

Home about blog pictures
*_*_-->

Comment: you mean a "standard" menu, and the line follows the mouse while it moves one the bar?

Comment: Yes but not directly mirroring the mouse, but just sliding along when a link is hovered over

Comment: I did something similar sometime ago, i'll try to find it and adapt :)

Comment: I just +1'd you, because ppl here are weak and giving -1 without a reason!

Comment: I think it's a nice question, even if it is a little too "open" :D

Comment: I'll try to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is: http://fiddle.jshell.net/KzFQB/25/  Of course, you need to adapt it a bit, depending on your div's width, and so on. But the idea is very simple, i think.

Hope it helps! ^^